# What can we say about $E(\frac{1}{X})?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose we have this random variable $X$, what can we say about $E(\frac{1}{X})?$

I alrealy proved to myself that it's not always implies that $E(\frac{1}{X})=\frac{1}{E(X)}$, but i know sometimes it does.

So, what can we say in general about $E(\frac{1}{X})?$ And when exactly does this equation $E(\frac{1}{X})=\frac{1}{E(X)}$ holds?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248472/expectation-on-1-x/248502 literally the first thing I found when I was looking for "expected value of 1/X"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983693     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910846      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248472